# How do you add attributes to Django users and register them publicly?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-1.7

I've been reading the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/customizing/

I have a fair grasp on the user class that inherits `AbstractBaseUser`. You simply create additional variables that you want to add and add them to `REQUIRED_FIELDS` as strings.

1. Are the functions, specifically `has_perm`, `has_module_perms` and `is_staff` required?
2. Are the variables `is_active` and `is_admin` required or are they just examples?

   As for the `BaseUserManager`, I'm a bit confused. I create 1 function, that takes every single variable/property of my `user` class from above. So it's about 10 properties.

   Then there is something like this:

   ```
   user = self.model(
       email=self.normalize_email(email),
       date_of_birth=date_of_birth,
       )
   user.set_password(password)
   user.save(using=self._db)
   return user
   ```
3. I'm not sure what `self.model()` is, but from the looks of it, I should set each parameter from the function and user property. Like this?

   ```
   user = self.model(
   email=self.normalize_email(email),
   variable2=variable2,
   variable3=variable3,
   variable4=variable4,
   variable5=variable5,
   variable6=variable6,
   variable7=variable7,
   )
   ```

Comment: Seems like you're doing too much work here. I don't really understand what you mean about the manager step, but you shouldn't need to do any of that. What method is all this in?

Comment: I'm just following the documentation linked at the top.

Answer (score 0):

`has_perm`, `is_active`, etc are used in Django auth, Django admin and some other 3rd party libraries (e.g., social auth libraries). If you're sure you will not use any of them, it's workable to define your User without these variables/functions.

`self.model` refer to the Model that the Manager assigned to. Example:

```
class CustomManager(models.Manager): pass

class Foo(models.Model):
    objects = CustomManager()

class Bar(models.Model):
    objects = CustomManager()
```

Then `Foo.objects.model` is equal to `Foo`, `Bar.objects.model` is equal to `Bar`. So `self.model(**kwargs)` is just same as `Foo(**kwargs)` for the manager of Foo. You can define default values in your model fields, then you don't need to pass default values again in creation of instances.